# <p:selectBooleanButton ajax is not firing the method

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to open a dataTable list when I click to selectBooleanButton. There is an ajax listener in selectBooleanButton but it is not entering the method on debug node. Here are the codes.

```
        <h:form id="form">

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
            <h:outputText value="" />
            <h3>#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.yetkiVerme.title']}</h3>



            <p:dataTable id="uyeListe" var="uy" rowKey="#{uy.kullaniciadi}"
                value="#{yetkiVermeBean.uyelerList}" paginator="true" rows="5"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                selection="#{yetkiVermeBean.selectedEntity}" selectionMode="single">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.title']}" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column filterBy="#{uy.kullaniciadi}" sortBy="#{uy.kullaniciadi}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.userName']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{uy.kullaniciadi}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{uy.ad}" sortBy="#{uy.ad}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.name']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{uy.ad}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{uy.soyad}" sortBy="#{uy.soyad}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.surName']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{uy.soyad}" />
                </p:column>



            </p:dataTable>

            <p:spacer height="20" />

            <p:selectBooleanButton id="viewYetkilerButton"
                offLabel="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.unshowAuthorize']}"
                value="#{!yetkiVermeBean.isRendered}" 
                onIcon="#{res['ko.plusIcon']}" offIcon="#{res['ko.minusIcon']}"
                onLabel="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.showAuthorize']}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{yetkiVermeBean.checkSelectionforYetkiVer}"
                    update="viewYetkilerButton"/>
            </p:selectBooleanButton>

            <p:outputPanel id="listePanel">
                <p:dataTable id="uyeListe2" var="uy" rowKey="#{uy.kullaniciadi}"
                    rendered="#{yetkiVermeBean.isRendered}"
                    value="#{yetkiVermeBean.uyelerList}" paginator="true" rows="5"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"

                    selectionMode="single">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.title']}" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column filterBy="#{uy.kullaniciadi}"
                        sortBy="#{uy.kullaniciadi}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.userName']}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{uy.kullaniciadi}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column filterBy="#{uy.ad}" sortBy="#{uy.ad}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{res['ko.yetkiVerme.uyeListe.name']}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{uy.ad}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
```

And this is my ajax method.

```
public void checkSelectionforYetkiVer() {       
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    isRendered = Boolean.TRUE;
    context.update("form:listePanel");
}
```

What is in leave out?

Comment: For updating icon and label.I have processed form but not worked

Comment: Check your javascript console for clues. Confirm that the request is being sent to the server and that no conversion/validation errors are holding up execution